# Comment Follow-Up Notifier?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments

Hey guys. Is there a plugin out there that can easily notify a user of a follow up reply to their comment? I used to use subscribe to comments but it hasn't been updated since 2007. Also, I think I remember being the 'unsubscribe' process to be pretty tedious or confusing. I would like it if each email had an 'unsubscribe' link at the bottom which instantly unsubscribed the user from that notification thread.

I would like to continue using the WordPress comment system. I don't want to substitute it for something else like disqus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Subscribe to Double-Opt-In Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-double-opt-in-comments/)**

Comment: Thanks. Does this one have an unsubsribe link in each email sent to subscribers?

Comment: I don't know.  I'd suggest installing it to make sure it does what you want.